# Why can i create ViewModel with instance

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-jetpack

I create ViewModel with ViewModelProvider.Factory in my fragment. Everthing work fine.

```
var reportViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,ViewModelProvide(RemoteDataProviderImpl(
        WeakReference(context!!))))
       .get(ReportViewModel::class.java)
```

But after i create viewmodel directly with instance and then work everthing fine

```
var reportViewModel = ReportViewModel(RemoteDataProviderImpl(WeakReference(context!!)))
```

It is simple ViewModel

```
class ReportViewModel(private var provider:RemoteDataProvider) : ViewModel(){
var posts = MutableLiveData<List<Report>>()
fun getPost(){
    provider.getComments().enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Report>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Report>>, t: Throwable) {
            t.message
        }
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ArrayList<Report>>,
            response: Response<ArrayList<Report>>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                val reports = response.body()
                posts.value = reports
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

What is difference this two code. If i can create viewModel with directly why i need ViewModelProviders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ReportViewModel(RemoteDataProviderImpl(WeakReference(context!!)))
```

will

- create a new reference of the viewmodel **without any scope** of the activity or fragment.
- A `new reference` of the `viewmodel` will be created in `onCreate` of the activity. ( **even if the activity is rotated or configuration is changed** )
- It **would not** observe the scope of the activity ,i.e, it would **exist** even when the activity is `destroyed` !

While

```
 ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(...)
```

will

- `Observe` the scope of the activity, i.e, when the `activity is finished` , `onCleared(..)` of the viewmodel would be called ! ( **Viewmodel would be destroyed** )
- `Same instance of the viewmodel` would `persist` even during the `configuration change`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ViewModelProviders` will allow Android to attach the `ViewModel` to the internal `ViewModelStore`. This will allow few niceties, like getting the `onCleared` function called when the activity or the fragment are destroyed. Another one is the viewmodel's retantion upon configuration changes (eg. orientation).

Answer (score 0):

Because when you change config(rotate the phone),
if you create viewModel with directly, the viewModel will destroy and lose all the data in viewModel.

But if you use `ViewModelProvider` to create viewModel, `ViewModelProvider` will save the viewModel instance and data, so you won't lose any data when config change.